# PHP# FUT get price

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-match-all

I have problem. I want get price player, using the preg_match but I get "-".

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.futbin.com/19/player/353/Sergio%20Busquets/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Google Bot");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

$downloaded_page = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
preg_match_all('/<div\s+class="bin_price lbin">(.*)<\/div>/', $downloaded_page, $title); 
echo "<pre>";
foreach ($title[1] as $realtitle) {
    echo $realtitle . "\n";
}
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: That's because that's what's in those `divs`: `<div class="bin_price lbin">
                        <span class="price_big_right">
                            <span id="ps-lowest-1">-</span>
                        </span>
                        </div>`. You don't see the `<span>`s because your browser is rendering them.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the source code of the page you will see that why are you collecting this  "-"

```
<div class="bin_price lbin">
   <span class="price_big_right">
      <span id="ps-lowest-1">-</span>
   </span>
</div>
```

You won't be able to perform that task by CURL because the values are loaded asynchronous and curl gets the exactly source code that you can view by right clicking the browser and selecting view source code (this is not the same as using the chrome dock or firebug (f12).

The solution for that is to use an browser automation software that can be programmed by any compiled language (python, java, c++). I recommend selenium web browser.

https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/